# Good long formulation for "defence of the doctoral thesis"

Tags: academic-latin

As a follow-up question to [Invitation to a thesis defence](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6195/invitation-to-a-thesis-defence/) I would like to ask what would be a good long formulation in latin for a dotoral thesis defence, like "defence of the doctoral thesis" or "oral examination of the doctoral thesis" in English.

- I know *dissertatio* but it is to short and I do not find it obvious that it **only** refers to the defence (oral part) since in many languages Dissertatio/DIssertation is a synonym for the whole doctoral thesis.
- In german you have the word [Rigorosum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigorosum), a short version of the new latin termius *examen rigorosum* (hard exam) used to designate a thesis defence. It doesn't seem to be a proper latin word that would be understandable for non-german speaking people (or at least understandable as a thesis defence).